# PHP display POST data in the form

Tags: php, html, post

How does one take an html post and pass variables back to an html form? I have a script which runs but when PHP responds to post the form data disappears on the reload which is not what I want. TIA

Comment: many many ways; pick one of sessions, ternary operator, cookies, pizza. I think I'll opt for pizza myself.

Comment: You can echo back the `$_POST` data into the form.

Answer (score 2):

after the page reloads you can get the variables using

```
<? if (isset($_POST['inputname']) { $myvariable = $_POST['inputname']; }else{ $myvariable = ""; } ?>
```

after that you can insert them as input values so values will still be there after POST

```
<input type="text" value="<? echo $myvariable; ?>">
```

Comment: might want to add a ternary, obvs this guy could use as much help as he can get.

Comment: ... in case you don't know what ternary is... `$myvariable = isset($_POST['inputname']) ? $_POST['inputname'] : "";`

Comment: isset check can be used to avoid errors, updated my answer.

Comment: What if POST hasn't been set yet? Then you'll get an undefined variable error when you try to print $myvariable into the form. That's what ternary's good for. Or at least do an `else` or define the var before the if.

Comment: Ops! Yeah my bad sorry. Fixed now

Comment: Yea, that's better, but you realy should take a minute to read about ternary operators.